# How to increase the font-size of quick links in Sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, modern-experience, json-formatting, quick-links

I'm fairly new to SharePoint. Previously a regular user who is now responsible for updating links and files.

[image]

My boss wants the link text to be larger which is actually a great idea as I hate microscopic text.

After clicking on the "Quick Links" web part and clicking edit on the link I don't see an option to increase the font size.  Since this is an extremely simple feature I must be missing it.  Where is it located?

I would like it to look like this:

[image]

I've been browsing and people keep talking about JSON formatting. I don't see an area to enter that type of data.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, refer to [this article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d4b8b3c4-8950-4407-9120-204b80fc35f9/sharepoint-online-best-practice-install-modern-script-editor-web-part-for-sharepoint-online?forum=odspproductsandservicesharing&prof=required) to deploy Modern Script Editor Web Part, then change the font size as shown below:

```
 <style type="text/css">
    .l_a_658c9e0a{

        font-size: 25px !important;
        /* Font Size */

        font-weight: bold !important;
        /* Font bold, italics, */

    }
   .label-253{
        
         font-size: 18px !important;
        /* Font Size */

        font-weight: bold !important;
        /* Font bold, italics, */
    }

    .labelTextWrapper-510{

        font-size: 25px !important;
        /* Font Size */

        font-weight: bold !important;
    }
</style>
```

Result:

[image] [image]

Comment: @OP, The exact selectors (like `.labelTextWrapper-510`) will not work all the time because the number in selector (`-510`) always keeps changing (even after page refresh). So, you have to manage it accordingly. Also, OP is "fairly new to SharePoint". So, it will be hard to achieve this using SPFx if you don't have development experiece.

Comment: Manipulating out-of-the-box web parts like this is unsupported.

Answer (score 0):

There is no SharePoint out of the box way to increase the font-size of text.

Also, you cannot apply JSON formatting to quick links web part in SharePoint.

---

If you or someone in your organization has experience in SharePoint/SPFx development, you can create a custom SPFx web part to fulfill your requirements.

Also, there is one SPFx web part developed by community members which supports changing font-size & color of quick links. You can use this web part if it works for you:

[SPFx Custom Quick Links](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-custom-links)

[image]